# Как правильно произнести даты?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

Регресс их продолжался до 1814 и 1815 годов.

Answer (score 1):

Первый момент. Если регресс продолжался до 1814 г., то как он мог быть и до 1815 г.?

Если дата неопределённая, а судя по всему так и есть, то лучше переделать фразу в **Регресс их продолжался примерно до 1814-1815 гг.** Произносится эта фраза как *Регресс их продолжался примерно до тысяча восемьсот четырнадцатого - тысяча восемьсот пятнадцатого годов*.

Comment: *Первый момент.* — присоединяюсь к вопросу, но адресовать его нужно В.Г. Белинскому :) Цитату его в вопросе слегка переделали, так что не грех и ещё подправить.